# Does humanity really transcend to become something greater, the overmind or simply consumed by the "predator" overmind?

Tags: childhoods-end

> [***Childhood's End***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End) is a 1953 science fiction novel by the British author Arthur C. Clarke. The story follows the peaceful alien invasion of Earth by the mysterious Overlords, whose arrival begins decades of apparent utopia under indirect alien rule, at the cost of human identity and culture.

In the end, most adults no longer exist on Earth due to no human reproduction with the few humans transcend with the Overmind, the Earth along with all life finally shatters into fine dust and is dispersed in the universe. Did the overlord intentionally slows down the technology of Earth, for preparing them and prevent their escape from the Overmind which will consumes all life on whether planet they visit?

Is the overmind benevolent or a malevolent predator ready to consume all sentient life?

Comment: In Clarke's story the Overmind is a predator and we are its prey. "Malevolent" seems kind of anthropocentric. To a pig or a duck or a carrot, *we* are malevolent predators.

Comment: @user14111 Did we both read the same story?  Nothing I can recall in "Childhood's End" implied that the overmind was a predator.  The name of the book itself implies that humanity transforms into something greater.  The overmind uses the overlords to help races that have the potential to transcend physical life to realize that potential and become something like the overmind.

Comment: @user14111 That's a weird perspective. We live in symbiosis with pigs, ducks and carrots. You seem to have a strikingly anthropocentric perspective. We domesticated pigs, but at the same time, pigs domesticated us. Both sides benefit from the status quo.

Comment: @Luaan symbiosis does not involves one species comsuming another

Comment: @Luaan Sure you're not thinking of dogs?

Comment: Why would you say that symbiosis doesn't involve one species consuming another? You do realize parasites are symbiotes too, right? In any case, pigs and humans are mutualistic symbiotes anyway, which might be closer to what you think of as "symbiotic relationship". Do you think pigs would benefit from _not_ being eaten by humans? Do you think tobacco plants will benefit when humans stop smoking?

Comment: Reminder to everyone judging this question: just because someone got a very different impression from the book doesn't mean that the question is bad. Even if you think it's because of a problem in their reading comprehension, or in how they were taught to misinterpret the book before they knew better, or whatever. If one person got this impression from the book, then probably other people did too.

Comment: @Luaan Indeed, many plants benefit from being eaten by animals, who then excrete their seeds, along with helpful fertilizer, away from where the plant grew, spreading it further.  The best way for an animal species to increase its numbers is for humans to like eating it.

Comment: @MontyHarder That's the obvious ones - the whole point of having a fruit is to have an animal eat it and help spread your seeds. The same is true for nectar and pollination, of course. But there's less obvious ones too. Grasses benefit from grazing (and lawnmowing). Not because it helps them directly in any way, but because they tolerate grazing better than other plants ("weeds"). Thus, the relationship between grasses and cows is mutualistic. And sure, we eat cows. But we also feed them, care for them, and protect them from predators. That's why cows started living with humans.

Comment: @Luaan  If you haven't seen Allen Savory's TED talk [https://www.ted.com/talks/allan_savory_how_to_fight_desertification_and_reverse_climate_change] on how grazing animals can turn deserts into lush grasslands, I heartily recommend it. It's heartbreaking to hear him describe how he once advocated reducing populations of grazing animals, thinking it was the only way to save the marginal grasslands, only to realize he had it backwards.

Answer (score 31):

The overmind does **not** consume humanity.

The overlords (acting on orders from the overmind) interfere in human events in order to prevent us from destroying ourselves before reaching the point where humanity can transform itself into a being similar to the overmind.

The overmind can recognize that  a race has the potential to become like the overmind.  It uses the overlords (whose race does not have this potential) to help those proto-overminds to "grow up."

At the end of the book, humanity doesn't disappear or be destroyed by the overmind.  Humanity transforms into an entity like the overmind.

The overlords force humans to settle down and be peaceful so that the last stages of the transformation will go smoothly.  This also prevents things like a nuclear war destroying us before the transformation is complete.

Really, none of the figures in the book are evil in any way.  The overmind wants to see those races who can transform into something greater actualy achieve it, and the overlords act as a sort of "racial midwife" to help each race achieve the conditions for it to transform.

The transformation is a natural thing, not forced by the overmind or the overlords.  It happens when enough members of a race live in peace without fear of each other.

The overlords brought about the conditions, the latent human psychic abilities did the rest.

---

As I interpret it, the overmind managed the transformation by itself.  I assume it was difficult and possibly traumatic, and that the overmind decided to help other races make the transition in a less traumatic way.

The overmind uses the race of the overlords to do the work of nurturing the races with the potential to transform into an overmind like existence.  The overlord race doesn't have this potential, and maybe would have died out as an evolutionary dead end if the overmind hadn't put the overlords to work helping the proto-overminds.

Comment: Yes, humanity's proto-overminds are helped to grow up. That's why the novel is named "Childhood's End", not "Overmind's Feast"

Comment: @WinchellChung: Humanity's protomind - only one.  All humans join to form a new "overmind" type being.

Comment: Aside from anything else, the lifetime output of [Arthur C. Clarke](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?17) was generally (though not invariably) uplifting in tone. Admittedly, when read from today's viewpoints, his work can now seem ambiguous in places.

Comment: I think somewhere in the book they do mention that if unguided humanity could instead transform into some pure evil

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103598/discussion-on-answer-by-jre-does-humanity-really-transcend-to-become-something-g), where you can continue as long as you want (@Quartz2, JRE, etc.)

Comment: @Andrey - not so much evil as malformed/cancerous. Some human cultures were starting to investigate paranormal phenomena scientifically and Karellen mentioned that specifically as a reason for their intervention in human affairs.

Answer (score 12):

It's not totally clear, for a few reasons:

1. We really don't have a strong conception of what the Overmind properly *is*-- the scope and scale of its existence, properties, and powers beggar the human mind. Further, all that is known of the Overmind comes directly from the Overlords, who supposedly have a more direct line of communication with it
2. We don't exactly know what humankind becomes. We have the Overlords' word for it, but they are variably honest with humanity as a whole and individual humans
3. Words like *transcend* and *predator* don't necessarily apply to the Overmind and its interactions with "lesser" beings. They involve value judgements which the novel doesn't equip us very well to make
4. The Overmind's designs are based in what it presents as an inevitable binary outcome: species either transform to become Overmind-like, or they never do. Among those that can transform, species either survive long enough to do so or die out. Assuming that those are true, the Overmind's actions would be more nurturing or conservationist than predatory. But we neither hear nor observe anything post-transformation, so we don't know how true this is
5. We only hear of *the* Overmind, singular. It's not clear if this is because there is only one Overmind, which all species join if able, or because it's simply the only active such being in our region of space.
6. Humanity was not in any way consulted or offered options. Even if everything we're told about the Overmind's plans is true, the Overmind's plans are still something that *happened to* humanity, and certainly ended human existence as we conceive of it. It's total guesswork what humanity (or *ascended humanity*, if you like) gets out of the exchange, or if humans would want it were the option given. But the tone of the story, along with the title, strongly suggest that preferring to *not* transcend is at best petty and shortsighted, and consigns the human species to indefinite stagnation or destruction

---

However, the last dialogue of the final human strongly suggests that the transformation is desirable and glorious

> The last human is overawed by what he perceives during the transcendence, and truly feels pity for the Overlords that they have to persist knowing that it is possible, but never for themselves.

---

I don't see any reason to think that the Overmind is in any way a predator or malicious (whatever else it may actually be), though the lack of human-understandable information makes any conclusions difficult.

Basically any possibility you care to imagine is compatible with the text of the story, as long as you're willing to assume the Overlords are not honest about things, but I'm with JRE: the story is hopeful, and suggests that we (humans) can leave bad things behind us as we move into a bright future which is all but unimaginable so long as we're encumbered with those bad things.

Comment: While the the Overmind can seem nurturing in the assistance of bringing a new Overmind into existence, I always felt saddened that it was at the expense of 99.9999999% of humanity.

Comment: @PeterM There's this weird jump from "it would be nice if humans lived in harmony" to "all of humanity has a single purpose, a single set of values, a single ...", yeah. There's precious few utopian stories that don't do that. I suppose that's why utopian stories tend to seem rather dystopian to (classic) liberal thinkers.

Comment: @luaan do you really think that it is sensible for few humans to transcend at the cost of all human lives and the earth itself? Also it is not really known what the few transcended has become of, becoming something disfigured and beyond any recognition by its human fellows, doomed to consume all other forms of life in the universe for etnerity

Comment: @Quartz2 Nope, I'm one of those classical liberals. For me, an utopia is a place where people can resolve their conflicts and differences without using violence, not a place where people _have_ no conflicts and differences.

Comment: @Quartz2 Do you think it was sensible for all but  one of several billion sperm to die in the attempt to create you? Particularly given that they had absolutely no idea of why they were participating in the race in the first instance?

Comment: @Luaan Absolutely, everyone thinking absolutely in the same way, same values is a bit scary, I also remembers a quote" If everyone is thinking the same, then somebody isn't thinking" It seems that individual thoughts cannot exist in such utopia

Comment: @ChristheHairyOne Did you ever consider why evolution "made" sperm this way, especially in contrast to eggs? Natural selection only has one mechanism and criterion - genes that are more frequent are more frequent. As weird as it may sound, your sperm aren't in competition with each other - their genes are. And they share most of their genes, so cooperation is beneficial even if only one "wins". Individuals are just vehicles for genes, the machines genes build to enhance their ability to be more frequent in a population. Is there any way in which the Overmind is analogous?